# PHP does not return a warning or notice on syntax error

Tags: php

When I run some php code with a syntax error, it does not show any warning or fatal error.
Instead, it shows the message below

> Server error The website encountered
>   an error while retrieving
>   http://190.168.191.32/administrator/reports.php.
>   It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly. Here are some
>   suggestions: Reload this web page
>   later.

What is the reason and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try reading the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are describing is a 500 Error.

PHP is setup to throw this when the error reporting is not public(production env).

If you want to see them from the browser you'll have to set

display_errors = On in you php.ini

Answer (score 1):

In debug environments, use `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` so that php reports all errors.

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini file. Especially check the options [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Or/And read the log file of your Webserver. On a typcial setup with apache on linux this is /var/log/apache/error.log