# show error instead of "Server Error"

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have recently changed hosts, on my old host if i had an error in my syntax the error would be displayed (showing me where the error was)

On my new host i do not see this, i just see

> The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.XXX.co.uk/delete_product.php?q=66550. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Is there any way i can show the error instead of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP does not return a warning or notice on syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502916/php-does-not-return-a-warning-or-notice-on-syntax-error)

Comment: @Shane, when you're creating a question please look at the list of questions that appears.  The first one would have answered your question.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand The first one for me is a question about ROR when I enter *"show error instead of “Server Error”"* into the "ask question" title. I wish you were required to enter tags first, it would make those results more relevant. This is a tough thing to Google, the best we can do it point the OP to another question that has the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On production systems, do not use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as it can show information you might want to keep hidden. Use the server's logs instead. By default apache for example logs these errors in `error_log`.

And, **anything** that is open to the general internet public is considered "production" in my opinion. Development means it is a server sitting in your own local network.

Comment: @Shane, on *nix based systems, usually in `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache`. But this all depends on the server config.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on error reporting.

Include these lines are the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you have access to edit the `php.ini` file, you can edit it and include the following option:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

These settings will help you troubleshoot code faster and makes it easy to identify errors. However, it is not appropriate for a production-level use. You should use the first method and then you can remove the lines once you've fixed the issues. On local development environments, it's okay to edit `php.ini` file and add the directive as mentioned above.

Comment: This is OK in development, but not in production.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on error reporting would work, but perhaps it would be better to look into the server logs.